# Structure have objects and cannot be copied

Tags: struct, compiler-errors, mql4

I'm trying to start with my first MQL4 expert advisor,

I've created a `struct` to handle my orders:

```
struct Order
  {
   int               pair;
   int               command;
   double            quantity;
   double            entry;
   double            stopLoss;
   double            profit;
   int               slippage;
   string            comment;
   int               magicNumber;
   datetime          expire;
  };
```

but it seems I can't do this:

```
  Order a;
  Order b=a;
```

the compiler hangs saying:

```
'=' - structure have objects and cannot be copied
```

How can I assign a `struct`?

Comment: Because you cant overload the operator like in c++, i suggest creating a function `assign` that will copy data from one struct to another, and you could call something like `assign(b, a);` instead of `b = a;`

Comment: Nope, `=` can be used if there is no `string` or dynamic array members in struct.

Comment: Also objects, simple structs don't contain objects, just numerics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [MQL4 documentation](https://docs.mql4.com/en/basis/types/classes) says:

> Structures that do not contain strings or objects of dynamic arrays
>   are called simple structures; variables of such structures can be
>   freely copied to each other, even if they are different structures.
>   Variables of simple structures, as well as their array can be passed
>   as parameters to functions imported from DLL.

`Order` is not a simple struct because of `string` member. So you cannot copy it with `=` operator. Either remove `string` member or copy it member by member.

Comment: Thanks this seems to be the problem, though I am trying to build the struct in a function, and I seem to be unable also to return the struct created in the method.

Comment: Same problem. When you return something from a function it will be copied. So returning complex structs won't work too. You can use pointers for that case.

Comment: What if I create the object in the calling function, and pass it to the called in a parameter?

Comment: If you directly assign a new struct to that paremeter it won't be changed. But you can change it's members, that will do the job i think.

Answer (score 5):

---

**My Recommended Answer**

You can use classes with pointers instead of structures, which cannot have pointers and can't copy with strings inside,

Examples are below,
http://docs.mql4.com/basis/types/object_pointers

Read this to understand classes vs. structures
http://docs.mql4.com/basis/types/classes

---

**Alternative Answer with char arrays ( But simple change to this )**

Define `char` array with a fixed size inside a structure instead of a string.

Can use
**`CharArrayToString( ... )`**
and
 **`StringToCharArray( str, array, 0, StringLen( str ) )`**
 to work with `string`s and `char` arrays

---

**Example:**

```
struct Order
  {
   int               pair;
   int               command;
   double            quantity;
   double            entry;
   double            stopLoss;
   double            profit;
   int               slippage;
   char              comment[10];
   int               magicNumber;
   datetime          expire;
  };

  Order  a;
  string str = "testing\n";

  StringToCharArray( str, a.comment, 0, StringLen( str ) );

  Order b = a;

  Comment( "Array " + CharArrayToString( b.comment ) );
```

Comment: Just a word of caution, not sure if it's MQL4 or C++, but using the char array trick caused me grief until I realized the stored symbols had characters bleeding after a round trip conversion, `USDJPY` vs `USDJPYCash` when storing the items in an array.