# Structure have objects and cannot be copied, despite no complex structures are present

Tags: struct, compiler-errors, mql4, mql5

I've got the following MQL code:

```
class Account {};

class Trade {

  protected:

    struct TradeParams {
      uint     slippage;   // Value of the maximum price slippage in points.
      Account *account;    // Pointer to Account class.
    };

    TradeParams trade_params;

  public:

     void Trade(TradeParams &_params) {
       trade_params = _params; // Error: '=' - structure have objects and cannot be copied.
     }

};
```

However, the [MetaTrader platform](https://www.metatrader5.com/) doesn't compile the file due to the following error:

> '=' - structure have objects and cannot be copied TestTrade.mqh   17  21

I'm using MetaEditor 5.00 build 1601 (May 2017).

I've checked this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26486359/55075), but my struct doesn't contain any complex objects such as strings. The suggestion is to use pointers instead of structures, which I am actually using. My goal is to have a class constructor with a struct argument as shown above.

What is wrong with above struct definition and how it can be corrected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this compiling issue has been fixed in the recent version of the platform.

I've compiled the same code under MetaEditor v5.00 build 1745 and it worked fine.

Comment: I would be very grateful if you could please help me out with this question stackoverflow.com/questions/60933737/converting-mql4-ea-to-mql5

Answer (score 1):

You should use structures in structures or classes in classes in MQL4/5. So, either:

```
struct Account {int m_accountNumber; };
struct TradeParameters {uint m_slippage; Account m_account; };
struct Trade {protected: TradeParameters m_tradeParam; public : };
```

or same with classes. Classes are preferred because you cannot have strings as structure members (you will have problems with copying and other manipulations).